# remove duplicate array from multi dimensional array by key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have the following array

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_scheduled_work] => 238
        [id_schedule_hours] => 1
        [id_truck] => 1
        [id_scheduled_work_details] => 209
        [work_order] => Z20160807211621

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_scheduled_work] => 239
        [id_schedule_hours] => 2
        [id_truck] => 1
        [work_order] => Z20160807211621

    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id_scheduled_work] => 240
        [id_schedule_hours] => 1
        [id_truck] => 1
        [id_scheduled_work_details] => 209
        [work_order] => A20160807211621

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id_scheduled_work] => 245
        [id_schedule_hours] => 2
        [id_truck] => 1
        [work_order] => A20160807211621

    )

  )
```

So i want to remove duplicate entires by work_order number so my final array should be and i also need to reset the keys so that they go 0 1 ...

```
  Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_scheduled_work] => 238
        [id_schedule_hours] => 1
        [id_truck] => 1
        [id_scheduled_work_details] => 209
        [work_order] => Z20160807211621

    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id_scheduled_work] => 240
        [id_schedule_hours] => 1
        [id_truck] => 1
        [id_scheduled_work_details] => 209
        [work_order] => A20160807211621

    )

)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: i looked at that but that seems to just move anything thats duplicated i need to specifically remove duplicates with work order only that match each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$key = array_column(array, 'work_order');

$result = array_combine($keys, array);
```

try it

Comment: my key becomes the work order number but i want the keys to just be reset to be 0 1 ....

Comment: im marking this as good i guess i can use array_values to rebase